# How can I append data onto a view using sql?

Tags: sql, dataset, append

I have created a view using the following sql command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Table AS
SELECT * FROM TABLEA FULL OUTER JOIN TABLEB 
ON TABLEA.Column1=TABLEB.Column1
```

I usually get new datasets every week and I was wondering if there was a way using sql commands to append the data from the new table onto the view, "Table"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  SQL is just a language, not an actual product.

Answer (score 0):

A view in SQL, so long as it is not a *materialized* view, basically just sits on top of the underlying table.  So, for a non materialized view, if you want it to see new data, that data would have to come from the underlying tables.  If you have a materialized view, then you may just insert however many rows you want.